# Unable to install PG gem on Fedora 17

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, postgresql, rvm, fedora

The pg gem is being stubborn so I can't load my app on new computer. Seems like multiple problems, not being able to locate pg_config and then extconf.rb

```
#psql working...
psql (9.2.1)
Type "help" for help.

nd =>
\q

$ pg_config:

#adding the path to bashrc...
$ nano .bashrc

PATH=/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin:$PATH

#seems to work...
pg_config: /usr/pgsql-9.2/bin/pg_config

$ sudo gem install pg

#but i get the same errors...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
.......
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

any linux people out there that have dealt with this problem?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

this is solved with

```
$ yum install /usr/include/libpq-fe.h
```

Answer (score 15):

For Fedora 20+, following package is needed:

```
sudo yum install postgresql-devel
```

Answer (score 2):

for fedora 30:

```
$sudo dnf install libpq-devel
```

then:

```
$gem install pg

Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Successfully installed pg-1.1.4
Parsing documentation for pg-1.1.4
Installing ri documentation for pg-1.1.4
Done installing documentation for pg after 1 seconds
1 gem installed
```

Answer (score 0):

~ Hi

I had the same problem installing the gem "pg" in my Rails project, when ran the command "bundle install" had the same error, in my case partiuclar solve it as follows:

I use Fedora 19, I guess it can be solved in the same way in Fedora 17:

I Installed Postgres using the following tutorial:

- > http://goo.gl/AhZZKR

Then, I added the next line in my ~/.bashrc to solve the problem with the pg_config:

- `PATH = / usr/pgsql-9.2/bin: $ PATH`

And finally to solve the problem with libpq-fe.h, I installed postgresql-devel as follows:

- `# yum install postgresql92-devel`

Finally in my Rails project ran the command "bundle install" and no more errors.